# How do I download global Hansen Global Forest Change data from GEE?

Tags: google-earth-engine

[I have been trying to download 4 bands of the Hansen forest change data](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/UMD_hansen_global_forest_change_2020_v1_8#bands) from GEE, and need the rasters to span the entire world.
I have been using the following code to do so:

```
var myStringArrayGFW = ['treecover2000','loss','gain','lossyear'];
var dataset_name = "UMD/hansen/global_forest_change_2020_v1_8"; 
var dataset = ee.Image(dataset_name);
var myStringArray = myStringArrayGFW;
    
myStringArray.forEach(function(s) {
  var name = dataset_name.replace(new RegExp('/', 'gi'),'-');
  var data = dataset.select(s); 
  Export.image.toDrive({
    image: data,
    description: name+"-"+s, 
    scale:5000, //5x5km
    maxPixels: 1e13,
  });
  });
```

Running this seems to work, as I can then save the files to my google drive, but the tifs I get are only a fraction of the size I need them to be (see picture below).[image: This is what I get for example, a 125ko file.]

How would I go about fixing my code such that it downloads the entire rasters?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour], which emphasizes the importance of asking One question per Question. Providing a bullet list of questions is a quick way to Question closure.

Comment: Thanks @Vince, updated my question to reflect this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specify a region spanning the whole world (easiest way is as a non-geodesic polygon that doesn't touch the poles); you're just getting whatever the code editor happens to be looking at when you start the Export.

```
Export.image.toDrive({
    image: data,
    region: ee.Geometry.Polygon([
        -180, 88, 
           0, 88, 
         180, 88, 
         180, -60, 
           0, -60,
        -180, -60], null, false]),
    ...
```

Comment: Ah that does it, great thank you!